# Create variable for changing node-names in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I was trying to draw multiple rectangular nodes side by side using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.675]
    \def\size{0.625cm}
    \node[rectangle,draw,line width=0.6pt,minimum size=\size,fill=cyan!50!black] (elem_0) at (0,0) {$x_0$};
    \def\anchor{elem_0.east};
    \foreach \txt in {x,y,z} {
        \foreach \idx in {1,2,3} {
            \node[rectangle,draw,anchor=west,line width=0.6pt,minimum size=\size,fill=cyan!50!black] (elem_\txt_\idx) at (\anchor) {$\txt_\idx$};

            \def\anchor{elem_\txt_\idx.east};
        }

        \node[anchor=west] (separator_\txt) at (elem_\txt_3.east) {$...$};
        \def\anchor{separator_\txt.east};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but unfortunately it seems that the `\def\anchor` is not updated inside the foreach-loop.

Is there any other way how to do this without unrolling the loops?

Comment: it helps if you provide a test file not just a fragment but tikz for-each puts each item in a local group, you can probably use `\xdef` instead of `\def` to be global and to expand `\txt`

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of `xdef` - it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

tikz `\for-each` puts each item in a local group, you can probably use `\xdef` instead of `\def` to be global and to expand `\txt` and `\idx` before making the definition.